# Variety structure of the Prüfer group

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

The group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ rather famously is isomorphic to the algebraic group given by the variety $X^2 + Y^2 =1$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$ with group operation given by $(X_1,Y_1)\cdot (X_2,Y_2) = (X_1X_2 - Y_1Y_2, X_1Y_2+X_2Y_1)$, and further homeomorphic in the analytic topology.  Is $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ isomorphic to an algebraic group over $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$, for $n>0$ or some power of an extension?

The topology seems to be an obstruction for a perfect analogue as $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ is discrete and a variety of dimension higher than 0 over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is presumably not in the analytic topology.

My attempt:
Suppose $G$ is a group variety over some power of an extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$. Endowing it with the analytic topology from $\mathbb{Q}_p$ we note that this is Hausdorff and a group topology. But any Hausdorff group topology on $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$ is discrete, hence our group variety must be discrete and thus $0$-dimensional.

Are there any significant mistakes or omissions in the above argument?

Comment: That is **not** the correct formula for multiplication. Check it again.

Comment: Also: Is the subscript p on ℚ and ℤ meant to indicate p-adic numbers?  Or something else?

Comment: Duly noted, yes $p$-adic numbers, integers respectively.

Comment: Besides the multiplication formula being still wrong, what is meant by the word "homomorphic" in this question? Perhaps you mean *isomorphic*?

Comment: I think your main argument is correct though.

Comment: Surely this time it's right. I mean isomorphic as groups, yes.